# UpdateOrCreate vs save() // Laravel no devuelve el valor actual actualizado

Tags: laravel, eloquent

la pregunta creo que es sencilla de entender.

Suponemos **cualquier** variable que contenga una **consulta** Eloquent, luego hacemos un **updateOrCreate** de un valor y **devolvemos la respuesta** hacia nuestro frontend.

Lo que **devuelve si hago un update con updateOrCreate es el valor antiguo**, Lo que me toca un poco la moral y me resulta muy **poco eficiente** tener que **volver a consultar para devolver el valor actual** del dato.

Se entiende mal? Pongo un ejemplo:

```
public function increment(Request $request)
    {
        $MathVentplayer = $request->user()->hasOne(MathventurePlayer::class)->first();
        $MathVentplayer->updateOrCreate(
            ["user_id" => $request->user()->id],                                                
            ["clasic_mode_points" => $MathVentplayer->clasic_mode_points + $request->reward]   
        );

        return [
            'status' => 1,
            'MathVentPlayer' => $MathVentplayer,
        ];
    }
```

En éste código de ejemplo, lo **único que hace**, al final, es **actualizar** esta columna:

```
["clasic_mode_points" => $MathVentplayer->clasic_mode_points + $request->reward]
```

Suponemos que antes de la consulta:

el MathVenturePlayer tenia un "clasic_mode_points" de 10.

el $request->reward es 5.

**Al enviar la consulta** y, efectivamente hacer un update correcto, el valor que **me devuelve es 10**, por que es el **valor que tenía en el momento de hacer la consulta.**

Si bien e tirado un updateOrCreate para incrementar el valor, **no veré este valor actualizado** en el return a no ser que **vuelva a hacer la consulta después del update...**

Es decir:

```
public function increment(Request $request)
    {
        $MathVentplayer = $request->user()->hasOne(MathventurePlayer::class)->first();
        $MathVentplayer->updateOrCreate(
            ["user_id" => $request->user()->id],                                                
            ["clasic_mode_points" => $MathVentplayer->clasic_mode_points + $request->reward]   
        );
        $MathVentplayer = $request->user()->hasOne(MathventurePlayer::class)->first();

        return [
            'status' => 1,
            'MathVentPlayer' => $MathVentplayer,
        ];
    }
```

Lo cual lo veo muy poco eficiente.

Otra opción es hacer el "update" como se ha echo toda la vida, tal que así:

```
public function increment(Request $request)
    {
        $MathVentplayer = $request->user()->hasOne(MathventurePlayer::class)->first();        
        $MathVentplayer->clasic_mode_points = $MathVentplayer->clasic_mode_points + $request->reward;
        $MathVentplayer->save();

        return [

            'status' => 1,
            'MathVentPlayer' => $MathVentplayer,
        ];
    }
```

De esta manera sí se actualiza el valor en la BD y en la variable que retornaremos como respuesta.

Pero... ¿**y si yo realmente necesito un updateOrCreate()** ?

Entonces.. ¿**De que manera** puedo **actualizar** vía updateOrCreate() y **responder con los resultados actualizados** ? (sin tener que volver a consultar la BD)

Se puede?

Gracias.

Comment: Podes ver el codigo de [updateOrCreate](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/9.x/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Builder.php#L577) no es muy diferente a lo ultimo que estas haciendo, solo que usa `firstOrNew` en vez de de `first()` y luego `save()`

Comment: Para obtener el resultado del updateOrCreate, Probablemente tengas que asignarlo a una variable `$result = $MathVentplayer->updateOrCreate(...`

Comment: Como dato, en vez de updateOrCreate, podrias usar [increment](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/queries#increment-and-decrement) para lo que estas haciendo

Comment: $result = $MathVentplayer->updateOrCreate(... <- así de simple! Vaya tontería la mía... muchas gracias! :). Muy buen aporte todo lo que me has comentado. Muy crack! muchas gracias.